# why I can't export export a declared function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have read docs from MDN, ok, mainly it's good about the new module feature, what makes me confused is the small things about `export`, now, let's see:

when I

```
export function foo(x) {
   return x * x;
}
```

or

```
export const foo = (x) => {
  return x * x
}
```

both works;

but if

```
const foo = (x) => {
  return x * x
}
export foo  // failed
```

I know here should be `export {foo}`, but, why? what's the difference, that should be work. glad to hear some genies ideas.

Answer (score 10):

ES modules support only several syntax variations in order to be statically analyzed.

According to the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax), the variations are:

```
export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, function
export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const

export default expression;
export default function (…) { … } // also class, function*
export default function name1(…) { … } // also class, function*
export { name1 as default, … };

export * from …;
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from …;
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from …;
```

`export foo` is not among them. It is not supported and cannot be used.

Comment: ok, thanks, maybe I just need someone tell me, 'that's the specfication! you have to follow it!', I really hope thing goes like between `support ` or `not support`, instead of  `limited support`, that just make people confused!

Answer (score 4):

> I know here should be `export {foo}`, but why?

Because that's the syntax that was decided for. Notice that it's actually possible to export multiple variables from a single export declaration:

```
export { foo as foo, bar as bar }
```

It just doesn't flow well without braces.

Comment: the point is I want to know  why `export` a function works, `export ` a constant works,  but `export` a function name failed, why do not just make them the same

Comment: Because the syntax for exporting *names* is with braces. Putting `export` in front of a function *declaration* or variable *declaration* is just a shorthand for that declaration and exporting it at the same time.