# <export const> returns `Cannot access ${fn} before initialization` but <export function> works

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

a.js:

```
export const(let) fn = par => {};
```

```
export var fn = function(par) {};
```

```
const(let) fn = par => {};
export {fn};
```

b.js:

```
import {fn} from './a.js'; // Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access '${fn}' before initialization
```

None of the above works, but if I try:

```
export function fn(par) {};
```

It works. Can I know why? Because not all the `export const` fail, actually most of them work.

---

```
// a.js
export const debounce = (fn, delay, immediate) => {
    let timer;
    return function () {
        const that = this;
        const args = arguments;

        clearTimeout(timer);

        if (immediate && !timer) fn.apply(that, args);

        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            timer = null;
            fn.apply(that, args);
        }, delay);
    };
};

//b.js
import {debounce} from './a.js';
const fn = debounce(...somePar) // Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'debounce' before initialization
```

This very ordinary debounce function is one of the failed ones.

---

I guess it might be hoisting issue but I declare it at the top just below `import`

---

This one works:

```
// a.js
export const toggleArrows = (arrows, method) => {
    const arrow = document.getElementsByClassName(arrows)[0].classList;
    if (method === 'hide') {
        arrow.add('d-none');
    }
    if (method === 'show') {
        arrow.remove('d-none');
    }
};

// b.js
import {toggleArrows} from './a.js';
export const goTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    toggleArrows('arrow-top', 'hide');
    toggleArrows('arrow-bot', 'show');
};

// c.js
import {goTop} from './b.js';
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', goTop);
```

Comment: I might be missing something but what is `const(let)`?

Comment: @Phil It means use 'const' or 'let' expression

Comment: this is a syntax limitation imposed by ES6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283458/why-i-cant-export-export-a-declared-function-in-es6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why I can't export export a declared function in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283458/why-i-cant-export-export-a-declared-function-in-es6)

Comment: @JGof that doesn't appear to match what OP is seeing

Comment: @JGof No that one was an export default issue I guess.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haze-qtls6?file=/src/index.js. I think there's more to your `a.js` or `b.js` than you're showing

Comment: @Phil Yes there's hundreds of lines

Comment: This looks like a [temporal dead zone](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-variables-and-temporal-dead-zone/) issue but without more details, it's impossible to answer

Comment: If you're seeing this, it likely means you have a dependency cycle in your imports, so the code in the question won't actually reproduce the issue, because it is caused by the combination of imports of several files all importing eachother.

Comment: This question cannot be reproduced in its current form. The code included works perfectly, the problem comes from elsewhere